# appending LinkedLists items to list using Recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have this:

```
def ppend(n):
    lis = []
    if n.rest == None:
        pass
    else:

        lis.append(n.first)
        ppend(n.rest)

    return lis
```

n is a linked-list [1,2,3]

The output I am getting is :

```
[1]
```

But the output I am looking for is:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `lis` list on every recursion. (Incidentally, you might try to find more descriptive names.) Only the first list is returned, however, because you don't do anything with the other lists that result from recursion. Instead, you simply call the function, which simply creates a new list without doing anything with the value returned by the function. You can see this in the following line:

```
ppend(n.rest)  # a new list is created but nothing is done with the result of the function
```

If you only plan to use the function once, you can simply move the `lis` assignment outside of the function:

```
lis = []

def ppend(n):
    if n.rest is not None:  # the first if statement appears unnecessary
        lis.append(n.first)
        ppend(n.rest)
    return lis  # or don't return it but simply refer to lis where you need to
```

The above approach, however, will not work as well if you plan to use the function multiple times and always need a new list. In the latter case, you might add a second function like this:

```
def make_ppend(n, lis):  # add lis as a parameter to be explicit, but you could rely on scope instead of adding this extra parameter
    if n.rest is not None:
        lis.append(n.first)
        make_ppend(n.rest, lis)

def ppend(n):
    lis = []  # now in the local scope
    make_ppend(n, lis)
    return lis
```

I am guessing you are after something like the second solution.

Comment: @Ali Great! I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thanks alot man... I am actually just starting to learn recursion... recursion is a bit technical in my opinion.

Comment: @Ali It does take a while to get used to, but you are on the right track. Keep using stack overflow if more questions arise!

Comment: oh yes... being new on this site i keep forgetting that there is a a accept button. :p

Comment: okay one quick question.. in make_ppend.. how are u apppending to one list.. I had done something similar to that.. but my programming wasnt working.

Comment: @Ali The name `lis` is a pointer to a single `list` object created in `ppend`. So wherever I pass the `lis` pointer, the pointer will always point back to the same `list` object at a particular address (most likely on your hard drive). The trouble you had is that you were creating new lists every time another recursion was made. Does that make sense?

Comment: ooohhh I see I see.. Yes that does indeed make perfect sense ! :D Thanks a bunch for taking your time out and helping me :). It means alot